# Can't kill process and uninstall package

Tags: package-management, virtualbox, services, process, kill

I had some problems: couldn't remove packages properly and eventually I did `rm -rf` to directories of Virtualbox.
Now I want to install Vitualbox again, but can't because system tells that virtualbox already running. I tried `kill -9 <PID>`- doesn't help. 
Every time I try `ps -aux | grep virtualbox` the process appears with new PID.
`

```
30507  0.0  0.0  15444   944 pts/0    S+   15:00   0:00 grep --color=auto virtualbox
```

I can't remove, purge virtualbox. And it seems I don't have inittab.

*Update: I'm not using those broken system already, but still would be nice to know how to deal with such kind of problem.*

Comment: That is not Virtualbox, but "grep searching for virtualbox"

Comment: can you reset the system and  sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-\*

Comment: @MeganFoxz I'm getting message then: Running VMs found   VirtualBox is currently running. Please close it and try again. Please  note that it can take up to ten seconds for VirtualBox (in particular  the VBoxSVC daemon) to finish running.

Comment: I would say back up and export your VM's and purge VB and reinstall it is this a option ?

Comment: @MeganFoxz What ? I would happy to purge VirtualBox, but I CAN'T - that's the point.

Comment: have you tryed this (1) sudo apt-get update –fix-missing

(2) sudo dpkg –configure -a (3) sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: Can you add the exact ’rm’  you ran? You can check it by running ’history’

Comment: @MeganFoxz 1st gives: The update command takes no arguments

Comment: Does `ls /tmp/.vbox*` return anything?

Comment: @M.Becerra `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/virtualbox /usr/lib/virtualbox /usr/share/virtualbox`

Comment: @steeldriver no such file or directory

Comment: Check what else is left of virtual box with `sudo updatedb && locate virtualbox`

Comment: @M.Becerra a lot: icons, xml's...

Comment: Try sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq virtualbox . You shouldnt need to manually remove folders

Comment: @MeganFoxz dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove virtualbox which isn't installed

Comment: @MeganFoxz after I substituted `virtualbox-5.1` to your command I got message that VBox is currently running.

Comment: have you restarted the system recently, I cant understand why VB is running shouldn't be from a fresh start up

Comment: @MeganFoxz 1 hour ago

Comment: @MeganFoxz I rebooted again - the same problem.

Comment: I see I cant apt-get virtualbox or virtualbox-5.1 but I can download the .deb for linux on there site have you tryed reinstalling with deb file ? (1) sudo dpkg -i name-of-file.deb

Comment: @MeganFoxz I tried - the same message.

Comment: well dam ... we spent enough time on this lol full restore in the options some where :/. ive never had some thing this stubborn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58645/discussion-between-meganfoxz-and-r-s).

Comment: I had the same problem. Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827733/removing-virtualbox-5-1-in-a-stuck-state).